# Getting scrollTop to work in IE Quirks Mode from an iframe within an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a rather frustrating time trying to force my page to scroll back to the top after submitting a form.

The code I'm trialling this with is simple:

```
$('body').prepend('<a href="#" id="testing">Click here</a>');
$('body').on("click", "#testing", function() {
    window.top.$('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
});
```

This works, as intended, on FireFox - but not Internet Explorer.

It's worth noting that I'm using the UWA widget format and my code is essentially embedded within *two iframes*. There is an iframe for the HTML template and iframe containing this widget. **I have control over neither of these frames**, nor can I give you the full code because it is literally thousands of lines of horribly-written, misaligned HTML and JavaScript.

Here are some facts that I've put together to see if anyone can spot the problem because I'm don't really know where to begin looking:

- In FireFox, this code works fine - clicking the link instantly scrolls the whole page to the top
- If I open the IE console the Page Default Standard is "Quirks Mode". Changing this to "IE9 Standards" fixes the problem, i.e. clicking the link scrolls the whole page back to the top
- Changing `window.top` to `window.parent` works in neither browser
- Changing `window.top` to `window.parent.parent` also works in FF but doesn't work in IE
- Changing `animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);` to `scrollTop(0)` works in FF but doesn't work in IE

If I run the following alerts in IE, bizarrely (to me), here is the output:

```
alert(typeof window.parent); // object
alert(typeof window.top); // object
alert(typeof window.parent.parent); // object
alert(typeof window.parent.$('html')); // object
alert(typeof window.parent.$('body')); // object
alert(window.parent.offset().top); // alert doesn't trigger, no further alerts run until this line is commented
alert(window.parent.parent.offset().top); // alert doesn't trigger, no further alerts run until this line is commented
alert(window.parent.$('html').offset().top); // 0
alert(window.parent.$('body').offset().top); // 0
alert(window.top.$('html').offset().top); // 0
alert(window.top.$('body').offset().top); // 0
```

In short, it looks like `window.top` is accessible and so is the `$('html')` element from there... so why can't I get my page to scroll unless I force standards mode in my browser?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded in `window.parent` at the time you are using it? `$` is not the same as `window.parent.$`. Different instances loaded in potentially random order.

Comment: Interesting thought. I load jQuery as part of my widget *but* there might also be a different version of jQuery loaded as part of the template HTML outside of my widget iframe. What code can I use to try accessing jQuery in a different way?

Comment: To be on the safe side use `noConflict` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ Though I don't see any way a parent's scope could affect/overwrite something in the iframe scope.

Comment: Thanks @SergiuParaschiv. No effect, unfortunately :(